# Advantages of Service Oriented Architecutre

Tags: web-services, wcf, design-patterns, architecture, soa

I searched on [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Advantages%20of%20Service%20Oriented%20Architecutre&oq=Advantages%20of%20Service%20Oriented%20Architecutre&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3.550j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Advantages%20of%20Service%20Oriented%20Architecture&spell=1), but didn't get straight answers that **what are the advantages of Service Oriented Architecture**?

Can someone please highlight some of the benefits of **SOA**?

Answer (score 1):

The two most important (at least in a practical sense) are:

- Small, manageable (i.e. **maintainable**) components.
- Services can be distributed across different machines. This makes
  the system highly **scalable**.

In other words: SOA is a good fit into the modern software development landscape with distributed teams and ever-changing requirements, be it functional or non-functional.

Comment: Small and manageable also leads to things like limiting damage when somebody makes bad decisions.  Or putting natural limits on the size of a refactoring.

Comment: And what's the second advantage?

Comment: Maintainable and scalable. Two things, right? (Btw.: I fixed the formatting to make this more clear also visually)

Answer (score -1):

It gives great deal of re usability to your code and enormous power to the business as well.

Lets say you start creating an application for banking, now you need to create a mobile app for the same, and if that's not it you have to expose methods from your service to Master /Visa for transaction.

Now in the above scenario if application has been designed with SOA in mind, then lot of code is reused with added advantage of centralized deployment.

Comment: Down voters, please comment

Comment: Your answer makes bold claims, eg. *It gives great deal of re usability to your code and enormous power to the business as well* - but is not sufficiently detailed to justify them. Additionally, your assertion that *then lot of code is reused* is simply not true and has nothing to do with SOA. Finally, and probably the worst of all, the *added advantage of centralized deployment* - firstly, this is no advantage, and secondly, SOA tends to lead to decentralization of deployment and management, not the other way around.